# localizedTitle in my iOS app with In-App Purchases

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm writing an iOS application and since yesterday i have problem with in App purchases. I receive list of products but `localizedTitle` and `localizedDescription` are `nil`.

I've read that about 2 years ago some people had similar problems and it was Apple's fault.

However today I've got message from Apple about all of my In-App Purchases:

> "In-App Purchases have been returned and are highlighted in the table
>   below"

All of them still have status:Waiting For Review.

So I'm wondering if it is possible that because of returning products i'm receiving 'nil' or is this (again) something wrong with apple?

Can I do something to fix it?

Comment: What exactly was the "message" from Apple? I presume if you have IAP assets that are not even reviewed, you should get bad data from the app. Perhaps I'm not understanding the situation since it seems you just have to wait for review to complete on the IAP?

Comment: Information from apple was: _We have returned your IAP product/s to you, since the associated binary was previously rejected. When you are ready to re-submit the binary, please resubmit the IAPs with the binary._ But as I wrote before products still have status **Waiting for review** like it was yesterday and week ago. Everything was fine then and I had access to proper `localizedTitle`.

Comment: I've added new product which has status **Waiting for Screenshot**. It is also available in `response.product` but this product as the only one in list, has proper `localizedTitle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution at *devforums.apple.com*

> https://devforums.apple.com/message/966757#966757

Basically it appeared that each product language had status **rejected** (while product had status **waiting for review**). Adding new language to each product solves problem.

Comment: Woah - cool find and odd edge case. Thanks for reporting back with a link and solution